# NumPy: A General Vectorized Method to Apply a Function Returning a Matrix to Each Row of a Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I am looking for a vectorized method to apply a function returning a 2-dimensional array to each row of a 2-dimensional array and produce a 3-dimensional array.

More specifically, I have a function that takes a vector of length p and returns a 2-dimensional array (m by n). The following is a stylized version of my function:

```
import numpy as np  
def test_func(x, m, n):
    # this function is just an example and does not do anything useful.
    # but, the dimensions of input and output is what I want to convey. 
    np.random.seed(x.sum())
    return np.random.randint(5, size=(m, n))
```

I have a t by p 2-dimensional input data:

```
t = 5
p = 6
input_data = np.arange(t*p).reshape(t, p)
input_data
Out[403]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

I want to apply test_func to each row of the input_data. Since test_func returns a matrix, I expect to create a 3-dimensional (t by m by n) array. I can produce my desired result with the following code:

```
output_data = np.array([test_func(x, m=3, n=2) for x in input_data])
output_data
Out[405]: 
array([[[0, 4],
        [0, 4],
        [3, 3],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [4, 1],
        [2, 4]],

       [[3, 3],
        [3, 0],
        [1, 4],
        [0, 2]],

       [[2, 4],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 1]],

       [[3, 4],
        [4, 3],
        [0, 3],
        [3, 0]]])
```

However, this code does not seem to be the most optimal code. It has an explicit for which reduces the speed and it uses an intermediary list which unnecessarily allocates extra memory. So, I like to find a vectorized solution. My best guess was the following code, but it does not work.

```
output = np.apply_along_axis(test_func, m=3, n=2, axis=1, arr=input_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-406-5bef44da348f>", line 1, in <module>
    output = np.apply_along_axis(test_func, m=3, n=2, axis=1, arr=input_data)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 117, in apply_along_axis
    outarr[tuple(i.tolist())] = res

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (3)
```

Would you please suggest an efficient way to this problem.

**UPDATE**

Below is the actual function that I want to apply. It performs Multidimensional Classical Scaling. The objective of the question was not to optimize the internal workings of the function, but to find a generalize method for vectorizing the function apply. But, in the spirit of full disclosure I put the actual function here. Note that this function only works if p == m*(m-1)/2

```
def mds_classical_scaling(v, m, n):    

    # create a symmetric distance matrix from the elements in vector v
    D = np.zeros((m, m))
    D[np.triu_indices(4, k=1)] = v
    D = (D + D.T)

    # Transform the symmetric matrix
    A = -0.5 * (D**2)
    # Create centering matrix    
    H = np.eye(m) - np.ones((m, m))/m
    # Doubly center A and store in B
    B = H*A*H

    # B should be positive definite otherwise the function
    # would not work.
    mu, V = eig(B)

    #index of largest eigen values
    ndx = (-mu).argsort()

    # calculate the point configuration from largest eigen values
    # and corresponding eigen vectors
    Mu1 = diag(mu[ndx][:n])
    V1 = V[:, ndx[:n]]
    X = V1*sqrt(Mu1)    

    return X
```

Any performance boost I get from vectorization is negligible comparing to the actual function. The main reason was learning:)

Comment: You can use things like `np.vectorize` or `np.apply_along_axis` to make arbitrary Python functions behave in a "vectorized" way, but these generic solutions will provide negligible performance  benefit over a standard Python `for` loop. To get any meaningful performance improvement you will need to be specific about what the actual function you want to vectorize is.

Comment: Thanks ali_m. Your comment and Oliver's answer provide the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ali_m's comment is spot-on: for serious speed gains, you should be more specific about what the function does.

That being said, if you still want to use `np.apply_along_axis` to get a (possibly) small speed-boost, then consider (after rereading [that function's docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)) that you can easily

1. wrap your function to produce 1D arrays,
2. use `np.apply_along_axis` with that wrapper and
3. reshape the resulting array:

   ```
   def test_func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       return test_func(*args, **kwargs).ravel()

   output = np.apply_along_axis(test_func_wrapper, m=3, n=2, axis=1, arr=input_data)
   np.allclose(output.reshape(5,3, -1), output_data)
   # output: True
   ```

Note that this is a *generic* way to speed up such loops. You'll probably get better performance if you use functionality more specific to the actual problem.